# Получить Request headers при аяксе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xhr

можно ли получить заголовки при отправке аякса, а имеено cookies?

Comment: у jquery.ajax есть целый сайт с документацией. её стоит прочесть.

Comment: Конечно я читал, я не нашел, как получить отправляемые заголовки

Comment: прошу прощения - ошибся. просмотрел исходник и поэкспериментировал и, кажется, такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

**Как получить cookie из ответа AJAX**

Возможно вы ищете заголовок `Set-Cookie`:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

Вы не сможете устанавливать или читать файлы cookie в запросах [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) («совместное использование ресурсов между разными источниками») через `JavaScript`. Хотя `CORS` разрешает запросы с кросс-доменным-началом, `cookie` файлы по-прежнему подчиняются правилам браузера для страниц с одинаковым источником, а это означает, что только страницы из одного источника могут читать/записывать файл cookie.

**Простое решение:**

Создайте идентификатор сеанса в обозревателе сети, используя `Javascript` `sessionStorage` для хранения идентификатора сеанса, затем отправьте идентификатор сеанса с каждым запросом на сервер.

Здесь подробно описывается решение:

[Запрос междоменного запроса Javascript с сеансом](https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session) (на английском)

Comment: Вы не правы. Я хочу узнать именно REQUEST HEADER

Comment: @Alexey, пишите в следующий раз ваши желания более однозначно, пожалуйста.